# Anonymous types add to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list and there's some anonymous types.In here i'm unable to get a return and also return here is 0.

```
public IList<Supervisors> GetSupervisors()
    {
        List<Supervisors> lst = new List<Supervisors>();

        var AllUsr = iuserrepository.GetList(x => x.UserId != null);
        var xRole = irolerepository.GetSingle(x => x.RoleName.Equals("Supervisor"));
        var yRole = iusersinrolerepository.GetList(x => x.RoleId.Equals(xRole.RoleId));
        var userIds = yRole.Select(s=>s.aspnet_Users.UserId).ToList();
        var supRole = iuserrepository.GetList(x => x.UserId != null && userIds.Contains(x.UserId)).Select(x => new {UserId = x.UserId,UserName = x.UserName }).ToList();



        return lst;//<-- in here lst return 0.How to add it to a list
    }
```

Comment: You haven't added any `Supervisors` to `lst` (its empty)

Comment: I'm going to add like this  lst.Add(new {supRole}); but there's a error.How can i do this

Comment: You should add to lst, you can use Concat<Supervisors> method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially you create an empty list:

```
List<Supervisors> lst = new List<Supervisors>();
```

and then in your method's body, you don't add any items in it.

Hence, when you return it the list is empty.

Furthermore, you can add *only* objects in this list, whose type is `Supervisors`. You can't add an anonymous type object.

From that you have posted, I would suggest something like the following:

```
var supRole = iuserrepository.GetList(x => x.UserId != null && 
                                      userIds.Contains(x.UserId))
                             .Select(x => new Supervisors
                              {
                                  UserId = x.UserId,
                                 UserName = x.UserName 
                              });
```

Then add the above sequence to your list:

```
lst.AddRange(supRole);
```

What we have done above, is to make a projection of each element in the sequence that is returned from the `GetList` to an object of type `Supervisors`. As a result, the type of `supRole` would be `IEnumerable<Supervisors>`. So, we can use later the list's `AddRange` method to add these objects to the list.

**Important Note**

Since I am not aware of the `Supervisors` class definition, I might be wrong using the property names `UserId` and `UserName` . If that's the case, you should correct it correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add the values to the list thats  why it return 0

```
List<int> _list= new List<int>();
        _list.Add(2);
```

[more](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-add)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SourceList].AddRange([TargetList]);
Please check the below link
http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-addrange